# sqlmetal.exe adding a namespace to the partial classes automatically

Tags: c#, namespaces, sqlmetal

Is it possible to add a namespace to all the partial classes that sqlmetal.exe generates? I could do this manually but would like it automate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `/namespace` flag when running `sqlmetal`, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx)

ex:

```
sqlmetal /namespace:nwind /code:nwind.cs /language:csharp mymetal.dbml
```